# The stone **in a balloon** with the mass of $m$ is falling from the height of $H$. Find the velocity of this stone. (Ignore the mass of balloon).

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

> The stone **in a balloon** with the mass of $m$ is falling from the
>   height of $H$. Find the velocity of this stone. (Ignore the mass of
>   balloon and air resistance).

I found the answer as

$$\sqrt {\frac{v^2_{s}+2Hg + v_{b}}{g}}$$

where $v^2_{s} = $velocity of stone, $v_{b} = $ velocity of balloon, $g = $ gravitational acceleration.

If this stone wasn't in a balloon, then we could do

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgh$$

Am I right?

Comment: What's the relevance of the balloon? Air resistance? Pressurized medium? measurement reference frame?

Comment: @Joffan What do you mean by that? There should be similar to my answer. You should get it also ignore the air resistance.

Comment: See the new edit please.

Comment: I wish Gimusi takes a look at my question.

Comment: Are you supposed to be producing velocity as a function of time? What is the velocity of balloon and stone at $t=0$? How many dimensions are we considering?

Comment: @Joffan that's not given but the options are too similar to my answer. The only difference is $2g$ or $g$. So, I wanted to know whether my answer is correct. The answer you will get is should be similar to what I got.